# Error no.154 with gulp in windows 8

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, bower, gulp-sass

i'm been trying to run gulp serve but everytime it throws this error. I have gone through many solutions given in StackOverflow but nothing solved it. I have Installed the lastest versions : Node, Git, npm, bower and gulp. The paths have been assigned also correctly.

[This is the error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ6PP.png)

[the error what i got after installing everything as admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrdYh.png)

Comment: this error has generally to do with file not present.. the installation command's you ran at time does not work with non-admin priviledges.. try running those by opening command prompt with `run as admin` option

Comment: @entre Thanks, But unfortunately even after running as admin the same error was being thrown. Do you know why such an error is happening. I have gulp running in multiple systems here and this is happening only in my system.

Comment: ENOENT.. is its not able to find certain file or directory on the file system which it expects to...

Comment: @entre thanks  how do i know which files are missing i have installed all the components up to date. is it a problem with laptop or installation.this is my 6 th time installing on my sysytem but still it showing the same error. i all the other systems it was working fine but in my system it doesnt work can suggest me some solutions.

Comment: @entre  hii ,problem is solved

Comment: how did you solved it?